# Finding the n'th book in a linear series of books

Tags: c#

So I have this graph with books I'm iterating through and printing them out.

```
public class Books : IBookFinder
{
    private Books(Books next, string book)
    {
        Next = next;
        Book = book;
    }

    public Books Next { get; }
    public string Book { get; }

    public Books Previous(string book)
    {
        return new Books(this, book);
    }

    public static Books Create(string book)
    {
        return new Books(null, book);
    }

    //This is the method I'm especially interested in implementing
    public string FromLeft(Books books, int numberFromLeft)
    {
        Console.Writeline("This is FromLeft method");
    }
}
```

All is well and good, but I want to implement a method FromLeft so that I can write out the name of the book from it's placement in the graph, given a number input. For example, if inputting "3", it should output "Twilight".

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var curr = Books
            .Create("Harry Potter")
            .Previous("Lord of the Rings")
            .Previous("Twilight")
            .Previous("Da Vinci Code");

        while (curr != null)
        {
            if (curr.Next != null)
            {
                Console.Write(curr.Book + " --- ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(curr.Book);
            }
            curr = curr.Next;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Input number to pick a book");

        var bookNumber = Console.ReadLine();
        int n;

        if (int.TryParse(bookNumber, out n)) //Checking if the input is a #
        {

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input was not a number!");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(bookNumber);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Any hints to how I can proceed with this?

Comment: Wouldn't something like this suffice? `var book = this; while (numberFromLeft-- > 0 && book.Next != null) book = book.Next; return book;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a method that itterates through the books x number of times.

```
private Books FromLeft(Books book, int x){
    for(var i = 1; i < x; i++){
        book = book?.next;  // Check for null if you're not using C#6
    }
    return book;
}
```

You might have to change some numbers if you get the wrong book.

RECURSION!!! lol

```
private Books FromLeft(Books book, int x){
    if(x-- > 0) return FromLeft(book?.Next, x); // Check for null if you're not using C#6
    return book;
}
```

To get the previous: (I don't know how difficult it would be to make your class static)

```
public static class Books : IBookFinder
{
    private Books(Books next, string book, Books previous)
    {
        Next = next;
        Book = book;
        Previous = previous;
    }

    public Books Next { get; }
    public Books Previous { get; }
    public string Book { get; }

    public static Books Previous(this Books previous, string book)
    {
        return new Books(this, book, previous);
    }

    public static Books Create(string book)
    {
        return new Books(null, book, null);
    }

    private Books FromLeft(Books book, int x){
        if(x-- > 0) return FromLeft(book?.Next, x); // Check for null if you're not using C#6
        return book;
    }

    private Books FromRight(Books book, int x){
        if(x-- > 0) return FromRight(book?.Previous, x); // Check for null if you're not using C#6
        return book;
    }
}
```

Comment: It could also be done with recursivity making it SO much fun ^_^

Comment: The recursion solution is a nice touch, hah. Thanks!

Comment: How could it be turned around, say if I wanted to count backwards? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @Khaine775 You're not storing the previous book. You'd have to store the previous one. That would be the only possibility.

Comment: A suggestion to how I could go about storing the previous one? I'd first have to iterate through it from left to right and then keeping the previous books in check with pointers or something?